# How to get values already selected in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 box made with an select element , i am using DWR to fetch values from backend. I want to set these values to select2 element so that it appears already selected. I have tried adding **selected** attribute using Jquery dynamically but it doesn't work. But when i hardcode an option element with selected attribute, its working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your relevant code

Comment: You can refer doc here https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try:

if set single value:

```
  $('select').val('1').trigger('change');
```

if set multiple values:

```
var selectedValues =[];
selectedValues[0] = "a";
selectedValues[1] = "c";

 $('select').select2('val', selectedValues);
```

if get value:

```
$('select').val();
$('#selectid').val();  //By id
$('[name=selectname]').val();  //By attr
```

or

```
$('select').select2("val")
```

Comment: Thanks that helped alot.
though couldn't make 
$('select').val('1').trigger('change');  work but $('select').select2('val', selectedValues); worked like a charm